# Cooldown starts only after command is successful discord.py

Tags: python, variables, discord, discord.py

I've been trying to find how I could make a cooldown command only after the command was successful. For example, in the code below it works well for the cooldown command decorator, only until the "now_amt" is the same as "max_amt" until that has been reached, it would send "amount is too full" but that was unsuccessful and if the user used another command to get the "now_amt" lower, the user would still have to wait the full amount of time, even when the command didn't do anything.

How could I make a check within the code to make sure the command was finished then it would start a cooldown until you could use the command again? And if the now_amt was max, then it wouldn't start a new cooldown.

```
@client.command()
@commands.cooldown(1, 3600, commands.BucketType.user)
async def new(ctx):
    global now_amt
    now_amt += 1

    if now_amt >= max_amt:
        await ctx.send("Amount too full!")
        return
    await ctx.send(f'{now_amt}/{max_amt}')

now_amt = 0
max_amt = 5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Command.reset_cooldown), the command object has a method to reset the cooldown. What you could do is raise an error from your command, then have an error handler to detect that and reset. Here is an example of what that may look like.

```py
import traceback # If you still want error traces for other errors
@client.command()
@commands.cooldown(1, 3600, commands.BucketType.user)
async def new(ctx):
    global now_amt
    now_amt += 1

    if now_amt >= max_amt:
        raise ValueError('Amount too full!')
    await ctx.send(f'{now_amt}/{max_amt}')

@new.error
async def new_error(ctx, error):
    # We must first check if its a command invoke error so
    # we dont get an AttrbiuteError, not all errors have a .original attribute
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandInvokeError) and isinstance(error.original, ValueError):
        ctx.command.reset_cooldown(ctx)
    else:
        # If you want to have tracebacks printed for other errors, add this
        traceback.print_exception(type(error), error, error.__traceback__)
```